# syntax error on edit button vb.net

Tags: sql, vba

Here is the code for my edit command. When I click the edit button message, a syntax error on the update statement pop up. But when debugging, there was no error.

```vb
    Try
        Dim SqlQuery As String = "UPDATE data SET archivedate = '" & txtarcdate.Text & "', filenumber = '" & txtfilenum.Text & "', filedate = '" & txtfiled.Text & "', section ='" & txtsection.Text & "', subject '" & txtsubject.Text & "' WHERE number = " & number & ";"
        Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand

        With SqlCommand
            .CommandText = SqlQuery
            .Connection = conn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MsgBox("One record successfully updated.")
        loadListView()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: syntax error on update statement

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query statement:

```vb
Dim SqlQuery As String = "UPDATE data SET archivedate = '" & txtarcdate.Text & "', filenumber = '" & txtfilenum.Text & "', filedate = '" & txtfiled.Text & "', section ='" & txtsection.Text & "', subject '" & txtsubject.Text & "' WHERE number = " & number & ";"
```

Lets pay attention on this part:

```vb
& "', subject '" & txtsubject.Text &
```

You missed the equals sign. Should be:

```vb
& "', subject = '" & txtsubject.Text &
```

So the complete line would be:

```vb
Dim SqlQuery As String = "UPDATE data SET archivedate = '" & txtarcdate.Text & "', filenumber = '" & txtfilenum.Text & "', filedate = '" & txtfiled.Text & "', section ='" & txtsection.Text & "', subject = '" & txtsubject.Text & "' WHERE number = " & number & ";"
```

And finally, research about SQL injection. It is a serious security problem that your code are suffering.

Comment: the error still the same no change

Comment: @TamiTamiko What exactly is the message?

Comment: syntax error on update statement

Comment: @TamiTamiko Which database you are using?